# Multi Client chat Server Java

Tags: java, multithreading, network-programming, serversocket

i am coding a multi client chat server.i have a server folder that contains Server.java and three client folders namely client1,client2,client3 containing java files resp.now when every client joins the server i try to send a text but the server does not picks the message.the problem is in the void run() try method. till the while(true) loop everything works.

### Server code:

#### Chat.java

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class Chat implements Runnable {
  Socket skt = null;
  DataInputStream dis = null;
  DataOutputStream dos = null;
  PrintWriter pw = null;
  TreeMap<Socket, String> tm;

  public Chat(Socket skt, TreeMap<Socket, String> tm) {
    this.skt = skt;
    this.tm = tm;
  }

  public void run() {
    try {
      dis = new DataInputStream(skt.getInputStream());
      String msg = "";
      while (true) {
        msg = dis.readUTF();
        Set s = tm.keySet();
        Iterator itr = s.iterator();
        while (itr.hasNext()) {
          String k = (String) itr.next();
          Socket v = (Socket) tm.get(k);
          dos = new DataOutputStream(v.getOutputStream());
          dos.writeUTF();
        }
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println(e);
    } finally {
      try {
        dis.close();
      } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### Server.java

```
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.TreeMap;

class Server
{
    public static void main(String dt[])
    {
        ServerSocket sskt=null;
        Socket skt=null;
        DataInputStream dis=null;
        DataOutputStream dos=null;
        TreeMap <String,Socket>tm=new TreeMap<String,Socket>();

        try
        {
            sskt=new ServerSocket(1234);
            System.out.println("Waiting for Clients");
            while(true)
            {
                skt=sskt.accept();

                dis=new DataInputStream(skt.getInputStream());
                dos=new DataOutputStream(skt.getOutputStream());
                String user=dis.readUTF();

                String pass=dis.readUTF();
                if(user.equals(pass))
                {
                    dos.writeBoolean(true);     
                    tm.put(user,skt);
                    Chat ch=new Chat(skt,tm);
                    Thread t=new Thread(ch);
                    t.start();
                }
                else
                {
                    dos.writeBoolean(false);
                }
            } //end of while.
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        finally
        {
            try
            {
                dos.close();
                dis.close();
                skt.close();
                sskt.close();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                System.out.println(ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Client Code:

#### Send.java

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

class Send implements Runnable {
  Socket skt = null;

  public Send(Socket skt) {
    this.skt = skt;
    System.out.println(skt);
  }

  public void run() {
    InputStreamReader isrout = null;
    BufferedReader brout = null;
    PrintWriter pw = null;
    DataInputStream dis = null;

    try {
      // Thread.sleep(2000);
      System.out.println("Send a text");
      isrout = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
      brout = new BufferedReader(isrout);
      pw = new PrintWriter(skt.getOutputStream(), true);
      do {
        String msg = brout.readLine();
        pw.println(msg);
      } while (!msg.equals("bye"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println(e);
    } finally {
      try {
        pw.close();
        brout.close();
        isrout.close();
      } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### Client1.java

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.Socket;

class Client1 {
  public static void main(String dt[]) {
    Socket skt = null;
    InputStreamReader isr = null;
    BufferedReader br = null;
    DataOutputStream dos = null;
    DataInputStream dis = null;

    try {
      skt = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 1234);
      System.out.println("Connected to server");
      System.out.println(skt);

      isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
      br = new BufferedReader(isr);
      dos = new DataOutputStream(skt.getOutputStream());
      dis = new DataInputStream(skt.getInputStream());

      System.out.println("Enter a username");
      String user = br.readLine();
      dos.writeUTF(user);
      System.out.println("Enter a password");
      String pass = br.readLine();
      dos.writeUTF(pass);
      if (dis.readBoolean()) {
        System.out.println("User Authenticated");
      } else {
        System.out.println("Incorrect username or password");
      }
      Send sn = new Send(skt);
      Thread t = new Thread(sn);
      t.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println(e);
    } finally {
      try {
        // skt.close();
      } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
      }
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: This code does not compile. The generic arguments in your `TreeMap` backwards and the `msg` argument in your `do` loop goes out of scope.

Answer (score 0):

After writing any value using an outputstream you need to flush it to actually send it.

In the Chat and Server class where you use DataOutputStream, you need to call this after writing data.

```
dos.flush();
```

In the Client class after sending data through the PrintWriter you need to call this.

```
pw.flush();
```

Comment: i am doing that in the finally statement. dos.close() and pw.close()

Comment: Closing is different from flushing. You need to flush it after you write to it. To give an example, when you go to the bathroom you might pee into the toilet (imagine that as writing one value), and then you might go number 2 (imagine that as writing a second value). Until you flush that toilet, nothing gets sent out to the world. When you close it, imagine that as putting the seat down. You can't use it until you open it back up.